# SVN recursive delete

Tags: svn

Is there a way to delete a folder, lets call it FolderX from an SVN trunk recursively? A quick search on google only tells me how to recursively delete all .svn folders and this is not what I want to do

Comment: What's wrong with "svn rm FolX"?

Comment: He's saying that there are multiple FOIX dirs spread throughout the tree. Your command would only delete one in the current directory.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try something like the following on a posix system:

```
find ./ -name "FolderX" | xargs svn delete --force
```

This will find all matching files/folders starting in the current directory and perform the action on them i.e. svn delete. I'm not sure how to do this in windows though without cygwin.

For win32, the commenter below suggests a similar solution (cmd):

```
for /R . %1 in (*.EXT) do svn delete %1
```

Comment: I really wish there was an equivalent Windows command prompt command for this.  I could install cygwin i guess.

Comment: Found it, I wanted to recursively delete all *.EXT files from my repository, which in Win32 command (DOS) prompt terms is:

for /R . %1 in (*.EXT) do svn remove %1

Comment: Here is the correction of batch approach. Put this into some bat file:@echo off<br> for /R  %%a in (FolX\\*) do svn remove --force %%a

Comment: Worked great recursively. One interesting thing is when I commit, I see only one line message: Deleting       archive
Committed revision 21027. Looks like SVN gets smart.

Answer (score 5):

`svn delete FolX --force` should do the trick even if there are unversioned files in the subtree.

Comment: He said FolX (for ``Folder X''), not FOIX :)

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name ".svn" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Source : [Recursive SVN delete](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/902/delete-all-.svn-directories-from-current-path-recursive)

Comment: It's not relevant. The question was about deleting from svn repo, not locally.

Answer (score 1):

I created a SH to run easily as a "rm" common.

- In "/usr/bin" I create "**rm_svn_dirs**" file, an put:

`#!/bin/bash`

`if [ $\# -eq 0 ] ; then`

```
    echo
    echo "Path not found"
    echo "Use:"
    echo "    $0 path"`
    echo "    $0 /var/www/test/svn/website"
    echo "    $0 ."
    echo "Operation cancelled"
    echo
    exit 1
fi

echo 
echo "Recursively delete .svn directories in:"
if [ $1 != "." ] ; then
    echo $1
else
    pwd
fi

echo
read -p "Continue? [Yes/No]: " x
if [ "$x" != "Yes" ] ; then
    echo "Operation cancelled"
    echo
    exit 1
fi

find $1 -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
echo "End!"
echo
exit 0`
```

- Save file, and make it executable:

  `chmod +x rm_svn_dirs`
- To use:

  `rm_svn_dirs /var/www/svn/www`

  `rm_svn_dirs ./svn/www`

  `rm_svn_dirs .`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to double the %, if you want to use it in an batch-file:

> for /R . %1 in (*.EXT) do svn delete %1

_

> for /R . %%1 in (*.EXT) do svn delete %%1

Answer (score -1):

It's worked well for me

```
find directory_to_delete/ -type d -name '*.svn' | xargs rm -rf
```