# Deleting all the contents of a SVN repository

Tags: svn, version-control

How can I do it? I just want to completly erase the contents of my current repository.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete all files from svn repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461553/delete-all-files-from-svn-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of a repository can never disappear.  The closest you can do is make it look empty by checking in an emptied working directory.   But all previous revisions are still tracked, with all the files.

I learned the hard way a few years ago not to check in giant data files on one machine and check them out on another as a way of "transferring" them.  It made my repo extremely bloated.  I used dump and load with some filtering to rebuild the repo without those giant files.

The best thing may be to delete the actual repository (not just its contents) - the whole thing wherever it resides and build a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

removing the repository folder will do the trick.

```
rm -r /usr/local/svn/repo
```

Answer (score 1):

[This SO duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461553/delete-all-files-from-svn-repository) says:

```
svn checkout --depth immediates http://myrepo.com/svn/myrepo myworking_copy
cd myworking_copy
svn rm *
svn ci -m "Deleting all"
```

As far as I can tell, since the repository is remotely stored, it would be easier to just remove it from the source and start from scratch.

Comment: I wonder why you go to the trouble of googling it and answering the question, then..

Comment: Actually, if I google the *exact* question the first result is this page! ... http://www.google.com/search?q=recursion ;-)

Comment: If you are going to copy a exact answer from another post, atleast [give credit to the original author](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461553/delete-all-files-from-svn-repository/1462886#1462886).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, that's pretty cool. Google does like messing with people (I actually clicked the "Did you mean..." link a few times to figure it out).

Comment: @OP, because now I know how to do it.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, I was *just* about to link it, really.

Comment: @blender I think you should be thankful for the +18 net points you walked out with for linking to a dup.

Comment: I think the reasons are explained above? duplicating some other answer isn't helpful

Comment: Wow, guys, calm down. If the OP neglected to look at the plethora of similar questions while typing this one, and considering that the OP has over 500 questions with almost no answers, I was guessing that the OP doesn't care to search on their own time, and it doesn't really pain me to do this. And @Scrum, I could care less about gaining reputation points. A simple question deserves a simple answer...

Comment: @Blender, then still, don't dupe the answer, but point to the dupe question as a comment to the OP

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that next time.