# Deleting a folder from svn repository

Tags: linux, svn, terminal

I sometimes make mistakes with svn and have folders stuck in my repository.  I want to remove these folders but I cannot figure out a way to do this.  Keep in mind I am very new with SVN.  I am running this command from apple terminal:

`sudo svn delete http://www.yourrepository.com/svn/folder`

I get the message :

```
Anthony-Work-Mac-Pro:htdocs APN$ sudo svn delete http://www.yourrepository.com/svn/folder
svn: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
```

I have also tried `svn delete`, and `svn rm`.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Looks like a commit message is required, and you do not have your system configured to launch an editor for you to add one (without specifying on the command line).

Try this:

```
svn delete http://www.yourrepository.com/svn/folder --message "Deleting"
```

Comment: Note that you can also use: `-m "Deleting"`

Answer (score 3):

To avoid similar messages in the future, add something like `export SVN_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"` to your .bash_profile (or something similar for your Mac :))

Answer (score 3):

You can use 2 step delete and commit for this as well. No need to use repository URL.

```
svn delete filename1 filename2 forldername1 
svn commit -m "[Message] Unwanted files and folder."
```

Answer (score 0):

I use powershell and the command `svn list -R` to search the repo recursively for folders I want to delete and then pipe the results into `findstr` or similar, like:

`svn list -r HEAD -R | findstr /R /I "\/obj\$/ \/bin\/$" | % { svn delete --force $_ }`

This uses regular expressions to search. Each /folder/ you want to find in the repo is separated by a blankspace, not the usual | (bar) character used in regular expresions.

Good idea to try it out first with just:

`svn list -r HEAD -R | findstr /R /I "\/obj\$/ \/bin\/$"`

Note to be absolutely sure what you are doing before commit.