# Subversion not ignoring my directory after setting property of ignore

Tags: svn, version-control, command-line, commit, svn-propset

I have a directory in my application called `/admin/debug/output` that contains a directory and a bunch of JavaScript files. I want to ignore them completely from appearing when doing an `svn st` before commiting code.

I used the `propset` commant like this to ignore it, however it seems to have had no effect:

`svn propset svn:ignore admin/debug/output/ .` ( I ran this from the root )

```
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
```

Why does SVN still recognise this when doing an `svn st`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SVN handles ignored directories only for immediate subdirectories and files. Thus, you should set this property for the parent directory, i.e.

```
$ cd admin/debug
$ svn propset svn:ignore output . 
$ svn ci -m "Adding SVN property to ignore output directory."
```

Make sure that **output** is without trailing slash.

**NOTE**

If the folder is already under version control, then the following sequence of operation should
be applied:

```
$ svn delete --keep-local output 
$ svn propset svn:ignore output . 
$ svn ci -m "Adding SVN property to ignore output directory."
```

if you have old SVN (<1.5) do workaround:

```
$ cp -rp output output_ 
$ svn rm output 
$ svn propset svn:ignore output . 
$ svn ci -m "Adding SVN property to ignore output directory." 
$ mv output_ output
```

**OR**

You can leave the folder and mark as *ignored* all files in it:

```
$ svn propset svn:ignore "*" .
$ svn ci -m "Adding SVN property to ignore all files in output directory."
```

Comment: Hmmm, yeah that's exactly what I done. I've just `cd admin/debug/` and then `svn propset svn:ignore output .` and an `svn st` still shows up all the JavaScript debug files. I used output _without_ the trailing slash.

Comment: Is that folder under version control? and how it's marked on output of svn st?

Comment: Yes, the `/admin/debug/output` directory is under version control. When doing an `svn st` both `admin/debug/` and `admin/debug/output` show as `M` (modified). All JavaScript files under those directories show as unrecognised, `?`.

Comment: So, you should set that folder out of version control (with svn delete = see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317600/deleting-a-folder-from-svn-repository) and do svn update, but should be done before setting the ignore property

Comment: I see what you're saying. Can't I have the _folder_ under version control, but have the files within the folder ignored? Or is that possible with SVN?

Comment: You can ignore all files in a directory - see http://blog.alastairdawson.com/2007/02/21/how-to-ignore-all-files-in-a-directory-folder-with-subversion/. But this is a bit weird IMO.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Do you want to edit/update your answer and I will happily accept.