# What's the best procedure for clearing out unwanted files in an SVN repo?

Tags: svn

I've got some garbage in a WordPress plugin repo I have that I need to get rid of.  I'm new to SVN and I'm apparently missing something here.

First, I do the following.

```
svn up
```

That pulls everything from the remote repo.  Then I just go through locally and delete all the garbage that doesn't need to be there.  So then I do...

```
svn stat
```

and I can see all of the stuff I deleted there with !'s in front of them.  So then I try...

```
svn ci -m "Whatever"
```

and it just gives me a new command line without doing anything.  Stat still shows the same info, and the remote repo still has all of the files.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317600/deleting-a-folder-from-svn-repository), and that does seem to work, but I've got a bunch of folders through-out this project with stuff that needs cleared out (garbage config files that Dreamweaver left behind.)

Is there some way I can easily do this all at once?  It sees the deletes I made locally, I just can't seem to figure out how to push those changes back to the remote repo..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete files in Subversion, you have to explicitly tell that to Subversion using the `svn rm` command:

```
svn rm path/to/file
# not the same as: "rm path/to/file" !!
```

If you have already deleted the files with simply `rm path/to/file`, it's not a problem, but you still need to execute the `svn rm path/to/file` command too.

If that's too much typing (probably it is), then you can use a bash one-liner like this:

```
svn st | sed -e s/........// | while read line; do svn rm "$line"; done
```

Probably it would have been easier to use a file browser that understands Subversion. For example TortoiseSVN or Eclipse with Subversion plugin or similar. When you delete files in these tools that are aware of Subversion, they will understand that you want to remove files from version control, and make this easier for you.